# Android Warning: Unchecked call to 'onBindViewHolder(VH, int)' as a member of raw type

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my adapter class http://paste.ubuntu.com/25481482/

I am getting the compiler warning ( Line 16 ):

> Unchecked call to 'onBindViewHolder(VH, int)' as a member of raw type 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter'

It compiles fine and works, but what's that warning and why does it appear?